# pandas - draw a distribution of a column

Tags: python, pandas

The DataFrame is as the following:

[image]

And I'd like to draw a distribution of population of the groupby geo_name, but when I use the following command:

```
df.hist(column='population')
```

The histogram is not each bar for geo_name's population:

[image]

For example, there should be two top bars from (Ont.) and (Que.), but there is only one bar which is much higher than others.
What's the matter? How to resolve it?

Comment: you are using the wrong type of plot. Histogram is for showing distribution

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a bar chart of populations, one bar per province, with provinces arranged along the horizontal axis. If so, try this:

```
df['population'].plot(kind='bar')
```